# JOIN and CASE WHEN - How to check for NULL and use that field to join 2 tables?

Tags: sql, join, case

Table 1 - `Sales`

```
| Country  | State | City| Sales_Amt
```

Table 2 - `Target`

```
| Country  | State | City| Target_Amt
```

Requirement:

- check if `t.City IS NOT NULL`, then join on `t.City = s.city`;
- else check if `t.State IS NOT NULL`, then join on `t.State = s.State`;
- else join on `t.Country = s.Country`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sales s
JOIN Target t ON s.city = t.city  (implement the above conditions here)
```

I have done CASE WHEN in JOIN when either LHS or RHS is constant. But in this case, both LHS and RHS will change based on the condition check and I am not sure how to implement this.

Comment: [tag:mysql] <> [tag:sql-server] I removed those tags - please add only the specific RDBMS you are actually using.

Comment: Your description is not clear. You are joining target rows to sales rows. This may get zero, one or many matches on each sales row. So, for one sales row, do you want all target rows with the same city plus all target rows with no city, but the same state plus all target rows without city and state, but same country? Or are you rather looking for one best matching row? Also, are you sure you don't care about country and state when the city matches? So Amsterdam in Montana, USA = Amsterdam in the Netherlands?

Comment: You are looking for a special treatment of nulls in the target table. Can the columns also be null in the sales table? If so, how to go about that? I suggest you show some sample data and the expected result in your request, so it becomes clear what you are dealing with.

Comment: What if `s.city` or `s.state` is null, do you want to join the nulls to the nulls exactly or is there some other logic for joining nulls?

Comment: @Data_Marketing_: Please do not forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) any of the answers as **The Answer**

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. The requirement may have some flaws since I modified the question a bit for easier understanding but the concept is very similar. 
For ex: I don't have City colun in my tables instead it is the name of the global Team names and they are unique. Since the table columns were very product specific, I had to modify it to get the solution to the problem on hand. 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Sales s
JOIN    Target t
ON      s.city = t.city
        OR (s.city IS NULL AND s.state = t.state)
        OR (s.city IS NULL AND s.state IS NULL and s.country = t.country)
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked and also made the code smaller and simpler.

Answer (score 5):

I think you could compose a set-based solution this way (not thinking too literally about the if/else if/else logic:

```
select * 
from Sales s
inner join Target t
on s.City = t.City

union all

select *
from Sales s
inner join Target t
on s.State = t.State
where s.City is null

union all

select *
from Sales s
inner join Target t
on s.Country = t.Country
where 
    s.City is null
    and s.State is null
```

Comment: This solutions worked but the solution offered below made the code smaller and simpler. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `INTERSECT` operator in a subquery

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Sales s
JOIN Target t
ON EXISTS (SELECT s.city, s.state, s.country
           INTERSECT
           SELECT t.city, t.state, t.country);
```

In newer versions of SQL Server you can use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Sales s
JOIN Target t
  ON s.city    IS NOT DISTINCT FROM t.city
 AND s.state   IS NOT DISTINCT FROM t.state
 AND s.country IS NOT DISTINCT FROM t.country;
```